# Cannot modify height value from QRect

Tags: c++, qt, qrect

The follow snippet results in my compilation yielding "error: passing 'const QRect' as 'this' argument of 'void QRect::setHeight(int)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]".

How can I fix this and also I've noticed that if I were to replace h -= 80; with h--;, the compiler does not complain.

```
int h = this->geometry().height();
h -= 80;
ui->datumTable->geometry().setHeight(h);
```

Comment: Either the `datumTable` object or the `geometry` function has been marked as `const`. I.e. they can't be modified.

Comment: why would the QTableWidget have a setHeight method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geometry()` [returns a const reference to a `QRect` object inside `QTableWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop).

It's meant to be a read-only *getter*. You should take a copy, modify it and set it back with `setGeometry` *setter* function:

```
QRect rect = this->geometry();
int h = rect.height();
rect.setHeight(h - 80);
ui->datumTable->setGeometry(rect);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
QRect g = this->geometry().height();
g.setHeight(g.height()-80);
ui->datumTable->setGeometry(g);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that `geometry()` in `datumTable` returns a `const QRect`. Not an easy fix unless there is a non-const version as well.

Comment: pretty sure the same code has worked in qt on windows, could this be a linux variant problem/bug ?  This needn't be a difficult problem

Comment: @johnsonwi Because the returned value is a const reference, so the compiler won't let you modify it.